# BufferedImage red mask

Tags: java

I have to take screenshot of some area on the desktop.
I am doing it this way:

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(area.areaRect);
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(current));
//then I paint in on JPanel
```

and every screenshot saved to .jpg looks like this one:

[image]

It doesn't happen for pngs and gifs.

I googled about this problem and found a solution, creating image by the Toolkit class:

```
Image toolkitImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(imageUrl);
```

but I have no idea how can I take screenshot with it.

Comment: How does it look for pngs and gifs? What exactly is wrong with the screenshot?

Comment: Just guessing, but I'd say it's the background's lovely shade of salmon instead of white.

Comment: Pngs and gifs are okay, nothing wrong with them. JPGs are red like this one

Comment: I'm guessing createScreenCapture is making an ARBG image and saving it directly to jpg without specifying the colortype will lead to funky colors like the one shown.

Comment: This is a bug with how the JPEG writer interprets the alpha value of the image.  Try either using a format that supports alpha transparency or paint the image to a non-transparent buffered image before you save it...

Answer (score 0):

The JPEG writer in `ImageIO` doesn't take the `ColorModel` into account when writing the file, as JPEG does not have an alpha channel. The Alpha channel is the `A` part of `ARGB` that specifies the transparency value for each pixel. [Most image clients will assume that JPEG don't have alpha values](http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2009/04/odd-coloured-jpegs-in-java-with-imageio/) as that is the standard behavior.

The writer in `ImageIO` will write a file with the colors shifted, like the lovely shade of salmon as background in the picture. This is because the writer will write down the values wrong when it really should be writing them in RBG.

The workaround is to paint the image to a BufferedImage with RBG as ColorModel. Here is some [sample code](https://www.java.net//node/646550):

```
// argbBuffer is the ARGB Image that should be written as JPEG:
WritableRaster raster = argbBuffer.getRaster();
WritableRaster newRaster = raster.createWritableChild(0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, new int[] {0, 1, 2});

// create a ColorModel that represents the one of the ARGB except the alpha channel:
DirectColorModel cm = (DirectColorModel)argbBuffer.getColorModel();
DirectColorModel newCM = new DirectColorModel(cm.getPixelSize(),
cm.getRedMask(), cm.getGreenMask(), cm.getBlueMask());

// now create the new buffer that is used ot write the image:
BufferedImage rgbBuffer = new BufferedImage(newCM, newRaster, false, null);
```